# How to migrate Google App Engine Project to Compute Engine completely?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

[We](https://madgeek.in) have been using Google App Engine for the backend services of a project which has been developed completely as a Gooogle App Engine Project.

Lately, the front end instances were consuming more than 60-70% of our project expense. Thus we decided to do away with it completely and migrate to Google Compute Engine instead.

Wanted to know if anyone has migrated their GAE project to GCE. I understand that GCE VMs could be dynamically spun up from within a GAE app, but we want to completely do away with GAE. ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws2VRHq5ars&feature=plcp))

As a last option, I shall host a Django project and use GAE files as the controller for the web services.

However, wanted to know if there are other potentially easier options for moving GAE projects to GCE while keeping the datastore integration intact.

TIA

Comment: Are you GAE services using standard or flex environment?

Comment: @DanCornilescu GAE is using standard environment.

Comment: I believe GAE standard is generally more cost effective than GCE.  Why do you think GCE is a better solution for you?

Comment: @JeffO'Neill GAE - Hosting a simple `laravel` project with minimum requests cost us 90$ per month where hosting the same on a VPS cost us 10$. The difference in pricing is the real concern as our product is still in beta stage

Comment: @silverFoxA, to give you another data point, my GAE app gets about 20,000 sessions a month and costs me $10-15 per month.  When I had minimal requests, I was paying 10 cents per month. Perhaps you are using SQL which I believe costs much more than datastore?

Comment: @JeffO'Neill Thank you for your response. We totally understand the above statement but it's certainly not clear why a `laravel` project which was kept idle no web service integration nothing (fresh laravel app implementation) costs 90$ per month. Would be really helpful if you could kindly enlighten us on that.

Comment: @silverFoxA, you'd have to provide more details of what you are doing.  I'm also a Python person so I don't know anything about Laravel. You said the charges are from instances, but GAE basically gives you a free instance a day for the whole month.  Why do you have more than one instance going at a time?  Do you have multiple services running?

Comment: @JeffO'Neill Sir, is there any means we can connect with you directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the uniqueness of the standard environment support for the application may make your migration quite difficult.

Take, for example, the significant differences just between the standard env and the flexible env (which, if you want, would be like an intermediary step towards total migration to GCE): [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating). To me they're practically different beasts.

To make matters worse the very thing you consider the most important in your migration - keeping the datastore integration intact - is also the most *likely* to stand against your migration.

That's because chances are that your app uses one of the [dedicated client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#google_app_engine_standard_environment_client_libraries), optimized for and only available to the standard environment GAE apps. If so - the migration effectively means re-designing the entire interaction with the datastore to make it use one of [the more generic datastore libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) instead. Which means more than just translating API calls - there are conceptual and functional differences that would need to be addressed.

So the answer to the title question may very well be: redesign your app for GCE. Personally I'm unsure if GCE is overall more cost-effective - I still prefer the standard env GAE. Assuming at some point the costs go up enough to maybe re-consider, I'd:

- take a closer look at the pricing and the current app costs breakdown, to see which components are the heavier ones: if the majority of the costs come, for example, from the datastore usage - I wouldn't expect a migration to GCE to significantly help
- try to tune the app's config and/or code to reduce costs: for example if the instance hours represent the majority in the costs tuning the scalability configurations depending on the actual traffic patterns *might* lower the bill
- estimate the costs for similar usage patterns but with the corresponding components available on GCE (and/or GAE flex)
- if the respective components are also available on GAE flex I'd make some experiments using that instead of going full GCE (which would pretty much require the re-write first).

A gradual transition using the flexible environment as a stepping stone could reveal if the estimated costs savings aren't quite there, thus helping drop the whole transition before doing the entire re-write. And also could help with the re-write, in case the transition still remains a "go".

Update: There *might* be another solution to consider for reducing costs: running the existing GAE app code through [AppScale](https://www.appscale.com/) (see also [appscale](/questions/tagged/appscale)) on a more cost-effective IaaS provider.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. The cost which is causing us trouble is the `front-end` instance. It's costing us more than 300$ per month plus there are certain pointers based on which we may have to opt for load balancers but our solution is still in beta stage and we have somewhere between 900-1000 users and some 2000 posts. The cost doesn't seem right. Neither the indication of opting for load balancers. Thus, we plan to opt for GCE assuming the instance is up for 730hrs per month and hosting all our projects it should cost us 30-40USD as a whole.

Comment: The cost has been a real issue for us while using GAE, even a small laravel project cost us 90$ per month where hosting the same on a VPS ex. DigitalOcean server barely cost us 10$

Comment: If you did your homework and you're happy with it - I'm fine. But, as mentioned, switching from the GAE PaaS solution to an IaaS one will likely require a significant re-design.