# What are the challenges in moving from PaaS to IaaS on GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

After reading available answers/comments on similar questions on this forum, it is now evident that GAE app is not straight-forward ready to be deployed on Compute engine. I fully understand that what all the managed services(mostly as APIs be it, datastore, document/index Search, memcache, cloud storage, task queues, cron jobs etc.), App Engine offered being a platform, won't be the same-fashioned accessible/integration-ready if available on Compute engine at all.

We have a 5 years old fully-grown App engine app now.
I am considering a scenario to support high-level of customization/control and adding third party softwares/middlewares to our server environment which is not possible with App engine. So if we have all solutions(Compute Engines, Container Engines etc.) other than App engine, to migrate our application to meet such requirements, what is the cost of such migration?

1. Need of server provisioning and configuration at Compute engines with different pricing model[Understood, should not be a problem :)]
2. Full or partial code rewrite to continue using the same APIs esp. Datastore, Cloud Storage, Task Queues, Cron jobs, Document Search, Memcache etc.[Need confirmation here and any reference/link to migration guide would be help!!]
3. Does this lead to risk of losing any managed service/API offered from App Engine? Document Search, Memcache, Task Queues, Cron jobs seem the possible candidates. Please confirm.
4. As per my reading, Big Query, Cloud storage, Pub-Sub APIs integration should not be much affected with such migration(Client-libraries or Rest APIs should still help!). Please confirm.

In nut-shell, We wanted it fully managed in the beginning so PaaS seemed the right choice 5 years ago. Now we want App minus platform-managed plus customized/flexible to our choice. How complicated this transition is going to be?

Answer (score 0):

> Full or partial code rewrite to continue using the same APIs esp. Datastore, Cloud Storage, Task Queues, Cron jobs, Document Search, Memcache etc.[Need confirmation here and any reference/link to migration guide would be help!!]

Unfortunately, some of those service only be provided on GAE, such as Document Search. But most of service can be use directly for GCP, such as  Datastore, Cloud Storage. GAE Flexible Environment is much like GCP environment, so you can read this article first [Migration to GAE Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating)

In following articles also have some answer：

- [How to migrate Google App Engine Project to Compute Engine completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172101/how-to-migrate-google-app-engine-project-to-compute-engine-completely)
- [Google App Engine Blobstore to Google Cloud Storage Migration Tool](https://opensource.google.com/projects/appengine-blobstoremigrator-python)

> Does this lead to risk of losing any managed service/API offered from App Engine? Document Search, Memcache, Task Queues, Cron jobs seem the possible candidates. Please confirm.

Yes, Document Search only available on GAE.

> As per my reading, Big Query, Cloud storage, Pub-Sub APIs integration should not be much affected with such migration(Client-libraries or Rest APIs should still help!). Please confirm.

Yes, but you may need to change SDK or library. It dependency on your language and how to call  those service by  Rest API directly or SDK.